# To get json values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In the below code i have json variable which hold value

```
[
  {
    "RegularExp": "[A-z]",
    "ExpressionType": "Alphabets"
  }
],
[
  {
    "RegularExp": "[0-9]",
    "ExpressionType": "Numbers"
  }
]
```

When i try alert **RegEx** it displays `[Object,object],[Object,object]`.when i try to get json parse value it throws undefined .Please help me to solve the issue.

```
function CheckRegularExpression(RegEx) {
        alert('1');
        alert(RegEx[0].RegularExp);// undefined
        alert(RegEx.RegularExp);//undefined.
    }
```

Comment: If you change your argument name from `RegEx` to `batman`, does that help? Pretty sure `RegEx` is a JS keyword.

Comment: `RegEx` has no special meaning in JavaScript.  `RegExp` on the other hand does.

Answer (score 0):

Alert function receives only string, and it cannot render object, so you must pass stringified version of Object.

```
function CheckRegularExpression(RegEx) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(RegEx);
}
```

And also, don't confuse people, your object is not a single object,

```
[{"RegularExp":"[A-z]","ExpressionType":"Alphabets"}],[{"RegularExp":"[0-9]","ExpressionType":"Numbers"}]
```

It's 2 objects, so basically single object looks like

```
[{"RegularExp":"[A-z]","ExpressionType":"Alphabets"}]
```

Sample below

```js
function CheckRegularExpression(RegEx) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(RegEx));
}
var MyRegEx = [{"RegularExp":"[A-z]","ExpressionType":"Alphabets"}];
        
function show(){
      CheckRegularExpression(MyRegEx);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="show()" id="show">Show regex</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`[{"RegularExp":"[A-z]","ExpressionType":"Alphabets"}],[{"RegularExp":"[0-9]","ExpressionType":"Numbers"}]` is not valid JSON; therefore, you cannot parse it using `JSON.parse()`. It's not even a valid array.

Answer (score 0):

You have JSON-like (but actually not proper JSON) string:

```
[
  {
    "RegularExp": "[A-z]",
    "ExpressionType": "Alphabets"
  }
],
[
  {
    "RegularExp": "[0-9]",
    "ExpressionType": "Numbers"
  }
]
```

To parse above string you can use below function

```
function parse_my_json(string){
   return JSON.parse('[' + string + ']')
}
```

Then you can access every element of this json:

```
parse_my_json(string).forEach(function(item){
   alert(item[0].RegularExp)
})
```

Test this solution:

```js
  json_like_string = '[{"RegularExp": "[A-z]","ExpressionType": "Alphabets"}],[{"RegularExp": "[0-9]","ExpressionType": "Numbers"}]'        
    
function parse_my_json(string){
  return JSON.parse('[' + string + ']')
}

parse_my_json(json_like_string).forEach(function(item){
  alert(item[0].RegularExp)
})
```